# Network Error Occurs While Making API Requests in Expo Go App

Tags: javascript, java, react-native, expo

I am facing an issue in my Expo Go application where I encounter a "Network request failed" error when attempting to make API requests using the loginUser and handleLogin functions. It is important to note that the same functions work flawlessly in Expo Web, successfully connecting to the API and fetching data.

I have provided the code snippets for both functions below:

**loginUser Function:**

```
export const loginUser = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Giriş yapılamadı:', error);
    throw new Error('Giriş yapılamadı: ' + error.message);
  }
};
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------**

**handleLogin Function:**

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await loginUser(username, password);

    if (response.message === 'Giriş başarılı.') {
      console.log('Login Successful');
      navigation.navigate('Second', {
        blogpost: username,
      });
    } else {
      console.log('User not found or incorrect password.');
      setErrorx('User not found or incorrect password.');
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorx('');
      }, 3000);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Login error:', error);

    // Check if the error response has a data field with a message property
    const errorMessage = error.response?.data?.message || error.message || 'Login failed.';
    setErrorx(errorMessage);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setErrorx('');
    }, 3000);
  }
};
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Linking, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { loginUser } from './fetchData';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';



export default function HomePage() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const logo = Asset.fromModule(require('../assets/LOGODEX.png')).uri;
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [errorx, setErrorx] = useState('');

  const handleUsernameChange = (text) => {
    setUsername(text);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (text) => {
    setPassword(text);
  };
  const handleSupportPress = () => {
    const message = "Merhaba, Uygulamanızla ilgili bir sorun yaşıyorum. Sorunum ise ...";
    const encodedMessage = encodeURIComponent(message);
    const url = `https://wa.me/SANSURED?text=${encodedMessage}`;
  
    Linking.openURL(url);
  };
  const handleRegisterPress = () => {
    const url =
      'https://wa.me/SANSURED?text=Merhaba%2C%20Uygulaman%C4%B1zda%20bir%20kay%C4%B1t%20olu%C5%9Fturmak%20istiyorum';
    Linking.openURL(url);
  };

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await loginUser(username, password);
  
      if (response.message === 'Giriş başarılı.') {
        console.log('Giriş Başarılı');
        navigation.navigate('Second', {
          blogpost: username,
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Kullanıcı bulunamadı veya şifre yanlış.');
        setErrorx('Kullanıcı bulunamadı veya şifre yanlış.');
        setTimeout(() => {
          setErrorx('');
        }, 3000);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login error:', error);
  
      // Check if the error response has a data field with a message property
      const errorMessage = error.response?.data?.message || error.message || 'Login failed.';
      setErrorx(errorMessage);
  
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorx('');
      }, 3000);
    }
  };
  
  




  useEffect(() => {
    const loadFonts = async () => {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'my-custom-font': require('../assets/Seanor.ttf'),
      });
    
      setFontsLoaded(true);
    };
    

    loadFonts();
  }, []);

  // Font yüklenmediyse bekleme ekranı göster
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 30}}>Fontlar yükleniyor...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }












  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>





    


      


        <View style={{ zIndex: 2, position: 'absolute', top: 116, left: 22}}>

        <Image style={{zIndex: 3, width: 160, height: 88, position: 'absolute', top: -76, left:77}} source={{ uri: logo }} />

        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'my-custom-font', fontSize: 21, textAlign: "center", color: 'white', fontWeight: '500', top: 23}}>
          TEST 
        </Text>
        </View>

        

      <View style={{ position: 'absolute',backgroundColor: '#607FF2', borderRadius: 350, height: 700, width: 700, zIndex: 1, top: -420, left: -230}}></View>
      <View style={{ position: 'absolute',backgroundColor: '#4C51C6', borderRadius: 350, height: 700, width: 700, zIndex: 1, top: -430, left: -250}}></View>
        
      <View style={styles.loginview}>
            <View style={{marginTop: 9,}}>
        <View style={styles.loginPadUsername}>

          <TextInput
            placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı"
            style={styles.padUsername}
            onChangeText={handleUsernameChange}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.loginPadPassword}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Şifre"
            style={styles.padPassword}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={handlePasswordChange}
          />
        </View>





        <View style={{flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 17, zIndex: 3,}}>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginAddButton} onPress={handleRegisterPress}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Kayıt Ol</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginPadButton} onPress={handleLogin}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Giriş Yap</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
        <View style={{ height: 30, marginBottom: 4, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", zIndex: 5, position: 'absolute', top: 268, left: 24 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: '#E9F4FF', zIndex: 5 }}>
            {errorx}
          </Text>
        </View>

            </View>
        </View>



        <TouchableOpacity style={{position: 'absolute', top: 580, left: 202, height: 80, width: 130, backgroundColor: 'white', zIndex: 3, justifyContent: 'center',borderRadius: 45,}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 22,textAlign: 'center'}}> Destek </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>




        <View style={{ zIndex: 2, position: 'absolute', top: 680}}>
          <Text style={{fontFamily: 'my-custom-font', fontSize: 21, textAlign: "center", color: 'white', left: 24}}>
          TEST
          </Text>
        </View>
        

        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: '#4C51C6', borderRadius: 350, height: 600, width: 600, zIndex: 1, top: 520, left: -15}}></View>
        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: '#607FF2', borderRadius: 350, height: 600, width: 600, zIndex: 1, top: 550, left: -30}}></View>
      
      



   
   
   
   
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#blue',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  textcenter: {
    fontSize: 70,
    marginVertical: 80,
    textAlign: "center",
    zIndex: 3
  },
  loginview: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FD830D",
    alignItems: "center", 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    zIndex: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 4,
    left: -66,
    height: 700,
    width: 500,
  },
  loginPadUsername: {
    backgroundColor: "#E9F4FF",
    borderRadius: 23,
    marginTop: 80,
    zIndex: 3
  },
  padUsername: {
    padding: 11,
    fontSize: 22,
    width: 210,
    textAlign: "center",
    zIndex: 3
  },
  loginPadPassword: {
    backgroundColor: "#E9F4FF",
    borderRadius: 23,
    marginTop: 17,
    zIndex: 3
  },
  padPassword: {
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: 11,
    fontSize: 22,
    width: 211,
    zIndex: 3
  },

  PadButton: { 
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 17,
    padding: 9,
  },
  loginPadButton: { 
    backgroundColor: "#8BC34A",
    borderRadius: 22,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginStart: 30,
    padding: 15,
  },
  loginAddButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#8BC34A",
    borderRadius: 22,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 15,
  },
  AddButton: {
    padding: 9,
    fontSize: 17,
    textAlign: "center",
  },

  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",   
}
});
```

**fetchData.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import axiosInstance from './axiosInstance';

const BASE_URL = 'API URL SANSURED'; // MySQL API URL'sini buraya ekleyin







export const updateUser = async (userId, updatedData) => {
  try {
    const newData = {
      ...updatedData, // Eski verileri kopyala
      izinyellow: updatedData.izinyellow, // 'izinyellow' anahtarını ekle
    };

    await axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/veridegistir`, newData);
    console.log('Veri başarıyla güncellendi');
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Veri güncellenirken hata oluştu: ' + error.message);
  }
};




export const loginUser = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Giriş yapılamadı:', error);
    throw new Error('Giriş yapılamadı: ' + error.message);
  }
};





export const updateYellowPhoneAndPass = async (useridpost, yellowPhone, yellowPass, xerror) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/verioku`);
    const users = response.data;
    const user = users.find((u) => u.username === useridpost);
    if (user) {
      await axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/yellowphoneandpassword`, {
        id: user.id,
        emailyellow: yellowPhone,
        passyellow: yellowPass,
        checkyellow: 1,
      });
      console.log('Yellow telefon ve şifre bilgileri başarıyla güncellendi');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Yellow telefon ve şifre bilgileri güncellenirken hata oluştu: ' + error.message);
  }
};




export const updateWhiteEmailAndPass = async (useridpost, whitePhone, whitePass, xerror) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/verioku`);
    const users = response.data;
    const user = users.find((u) => u.username === useridpost);
    if (user) {
      await axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/whiteemailandpassword`, {
        id: user.id,
        emailwhite: whitePhone,
        passwhite: whitePass,
        checkwhite: 1,
      });
      console.log('Yellow telefon ve şifre bilgileri başarıyla güncellendi');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Yellow telefon ve şifre bilgileri güncellenirken hata oluştu: ' + error.message);
  }
};








export const updateYellowTimeCode = async (useridpost, yellowTimeCode, yellowWork, yellowMesaj) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/verioku`);
    const users = response.data;
    const user = users.find((u) => u.username === useridpost);
    if (user) {
      await axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/yellowtimecode`, {
        id: user.id,
        timecodeyellow: yellowTimeCode,
        workyellow: yellowWork,
        mesajyellow: yellowMesaj,
      });
      console.log('Time Ayarlandı');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Time HATA : ' + error.message);
  }
};













export const updateWhiteTimeCode = async (useridpost, whiteTimeCode, whiteWork, whiteMesaj) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/verioku`);
    const users = response.data;
    const user = users.find((u) => u.username === useridpost);
    if (user) {
      await axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/whitetimecode`, {
        id: user.id,
        timecodewhite: whiteTimeCode,
        workwhite: whiteWork,
        mesajwhite: whiteMesaj,
      });
      console.log('Time Ayarlandı');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Time HATA : ' + error.message);
  }
};








export const getYellowError = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/yellowerror`);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Yellow hatalarını alırken bir hata oluştu: ' + error.message);
  }
};
```

The issue is specifically occurring in Expo Go on both Android devices where I have tested the app. I have verified that both devices have an active internet connection. The API works as expected on Expo Web, so I am puzzled as to why I am encountering network errors in Expo Go.

I have checked the permissions on the real devices, and the necessary internet permissions are granted to the app. Additionally, SSL certificate configuration seems to be in order as the API functions without any issues on Expo Web.

I am seeking guidance to understand the root cause of this issue and find a solution to ensure my Expo Go app can make successful API requests.

Any assistance or insights into resolving this network error in Expo Go would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help! **yes my english is bad i used translation while writing**

Answer (score 0):

check your api url ,use ip address instead of http://localhost:3000 use http:191.168....:5000 instead.Check the exact address of the machine on which you are running the backend. That's how I solved mine.

Comment: sorry you didn't understand